# Looking to identify this plug on a Bluestream Device

Tags: plug

I have a couple of these Bluestream devices that convert HMDI to TCPIP to transmit the video (and audio) a longer distance.  One has been iffy for a while and I have finally isolated it to the power supply.  The wire appears to be broken right next to the connector.  This is not altogether a surprise seeing that the connector screws in and the installer was obviously **not** careful about **not** twisting the cable.

I can repair this myself but I need to identify and buy the connector.  What is it called?

The Plug

[image]

The device

[image]

Comment: You're showing the least interesting side of the plug. What does its end look like?

Comment: If the plug housing isn't overmolded, you may be able to slide it back off the plug body and re-terminate the cable.